# using sed to loop through records in a file and use grep on all records

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am trying to find strings from one file in another file and I need to have the search string printed once, and the lines for matches following.

The strings I want to find matches for are in a file with 2 lines per record, no empty lines etc. Line 1 contains the name, line 2 the string I need to find in the second file. `sed -n '1~2p'` will print all the names, but I will need to print only the first name, pass the value of the second line to grep, execute the grep command, then print the second record's name (line 3), pass line 4 to grep and so on.
An alternative would be to use a `while` or `until` loop with a counter incremented by 2, but then I don't know how to pass the value of counter to `sed`.

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/973677/edit) and add an example with input and desired output using the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I apologize, I overlooked your comment.  I have only two files. the first is miRNA.fasta:
>vvi-miR390   
AAGCTCAGGAGGGATAGCGCC  
>vvi-miR408   
ATGCACTGCCTCTTCCCTGGC  
>vvi-miR169d   
CAGCCAAGAATGATTTGCCGG  
 The second is similar, RNAseqReads.fasta, but with much longer strings.
output in new comment

Comment: output I am thinking about would be:

>vvi-miR390

>RNAseq Read Name 1 
CTTTGCCAGGACTTTGGTTCCTGAAAGGTAGATGTCCACGTGGCAAATTGCTGCTGCCAC
A
--
>RNAseq Read Name 2 
AAACAATACTTTGATCCACTTGCTAATTCAAAGCCTTGAAGAAATCAAAGAGCTCCGCGC

--
>vvi-miR408 MIMAT0005733 Vitis vinifera miR408
>RNAseq Read Name 3
CCACTTCTGTTGGAGTGGTAGTAGCCCGTTGTGAGACAACGCCACGTACCATTTTCAGT
TTTCCTAGCCCAAATCCCCATGAACAGAACTCCCACGGTCAATAAGTTTCAACAGGATCC

Comment: Please **always** add additional information directly to your question by [editing](https://askubuntu.com/posts/973677/edit) it rather than commenting! That's why I linked you the formatting tools…

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, then given

```
$ head File\ {1..3}
==> File 1 <==
foo
Pattern 1
bar

==> File 2 <==
foo
bar
baz

==> File 3 <==
Pattern 3
foo
baz
```

and

```
$ cat infile
File 1
Pattern 1
File 2
Pattern 2
File 3
Pattern 3
```

then

```
$ sed -E '$!N; s/(.*)\n(.*)/grep -H -- "\2" "\1"/e' infile
File 1:Pattern 1

File 3:Pattern 3
```

or

```
$ while read -r file; do 
    if read -r pattern; then grep -H -- "$pattern" "$file"; fi
  done < infile 
File 1:Pattern 1
File 3:Pattern 3
```

Comment: not sure that I understand the answer.

Comment: @Susanne Then provide more information [like I asked you to do](https://askubuntu.com/questions/973677/using-sed-to-loop-through-records-in-a-file-and-use-grep-on-all-records#comment1561031_973677).